# Git ignore a folder that should not be ignored

Tags: git, gitignore

I updated my `.gitignore` from my [dotfiles](https://github.com/Soullivaneuh/dotfiles) like this

```
/.config/*
!/.config/tmuxinator/
/.vim/.netrwhist
/.vim/autoload/plug.vim
/.vim/plugged/
```

But git is still ignoring the `/.config/tmuxinator/` directory:

```
~/dotfiles master*
❯ git check-ignore -v .config/tmuxinator ; echo $?
.gitignore:2:!/.config/tmuxinator/  .config/tmuxinator
0

~/dotfiles master*
❯ git add .config/tmuxinator

~/dotfiles master*
❯ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .zsh/06_gem.zsh

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

~/dotfiles master*
❯ git --version
git version 2.19.1
```

Did I missed something?

I could force the add but I would like to do it properly.

Thanks

Comment: Works for me on git 2.15.1. Do you have any files in the directory? Git works with files and ignores empty directories.

Answer (score 0):

Well, next time, just don't forget to add a file on the targeted directory...

So it was a user/chair interface issue. :-)